# Restart Formik form after submitting from parent

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have following component where I'm calling my form:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import GuestsList from "./GuestsList";
import GuestsForm from "./GuestsForm";

const initialValues = [
  { id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Snow", email: "john@snow.com" },
  { id: 2, firstName: "Jack", lastName: "Frost", email: "jack@frost.com" },
];
var nextId = 3;
function GuestsManagementForm() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialValues);
  function parentSubmit(value) {
    const newRecord = {
      id: nextId++,
      firstName: value.firstName,
      lastName: value.lastName,
      email: value.email,
    };
    setData([...data, newRecord]);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <GuestsForm onSubmit={parentSubmit} />
      <br></br>
      <GuestsList listings={data} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default GuestsManagementForm;
```

and this is how it looks in GuestsForm component:

```
import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

function GuestsForm(props) {
  function onReset(values) {
    console.log("Reset form");
    console.log(values);
  }
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ firstName: "", lastName: "", email: "" }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object({
        firstName: Yup.string()
          .max(15, "Must be max 15 characters")
          .required("Required"),
        lastName: Yup.string()
          .max(20, "Must be max 20 characters")
          .required("Required"),
        email: Yup.string().email("Invalid email address").required("Required"),
      })}
      onSubmit={props.onSubmit}
    >
      <Form>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
        <Field name="firstName" type="text" />
        <ErrorMessage name="firstName" />
        <br></br>
        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <Field name="lastName" type="text" />
        <ErrorMessage name="lastName" />
        <br></br>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
        <Field name="email" type="email" />
        <ErrorMessage name="email" />
        <br></br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" onClick={onReset}>Reset</button>
      </Form>
    </Formik>
  );
}

export default GuestsForm;
```

I've succeeded in restarting from with explicit button press that is placed in `GuestsForm` component, but I don't now how to make it work after successful submit, which is now processed in parent component.
Additionally, I'd like to be able to add some extra logic to what happens once fields are restarted - e.g. I'd like to later print out what values were restarted.

I've found following suggestion in Formik's documentation, but I'm not sure if this has is applicable here (I've placed it inside `GuestsForm` instead of current onSubmit):

```
onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        props.onSubmit(values).then(() => {
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
          actions.resetForm({
            values: { firstName: "", lastName: "", email: "" },
          });
        });
      }}
```

One tested it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Based on example from Formik's documentation I have found solution to my restart issue. To achieve this I should have the following `onSubmit`:

```
onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        props.onSubmit(values);
        actions.setSubmitting(false);
        actions.resetForm({
          values: { firstName: "", lastName: "", email: "" },
        });
      }}
```